# Return binary response from Angular's MockBackend

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have tests that use Angular's [`MockBackend`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html) class to mock a server. I can send *text* responses from my mock backend easily enough by just embedding them in my JavaScript as strings...

```
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

// ... injection of `backend` as a `MockBackend` omitted ...

backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
  if (connection.request.url === 'http://example.com/some-endpoint') {
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
      body: 'whatever text I want goes here'
    })));
  }
});
```

However, some of the code I need to test involves doing clever things with a binary file returned from a server. How can I provide a mock binary response (from some static file specified at compilation time) using `MockBackend`?

Comment: Have you tried to load the contents of this file to variable with Webpack `raw-loader`?